# how to find max min from nested typed object array using RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

given I have this

```
type DataTableType = {
  name: string;
  series: {
    name: string;
    value: number;
  }[];
}[];

let datatable: DataTableType = [
    {
      name: 'Row 1',
      series: [
        {
          name:'Series 1',
          value:7110
        },
        {
          name:'Series 2',
          value:8240
        },
        {
          name:'Series 3',
          value:2111
        },
        {
          name:'Series 4',
          value:3120
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Row 2',
      series: [
        {
          name:'Series 1',
          value:6500
        },
        {
          name:'Series 2',
          value:9120
        },
        {
          name:'Series 3',
          value:5123
        },
        {
          name:'Series 4',
          value:8200
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Row 3',
      series: [
        {
          name:'Series 1',
          value:-6453
        },
        {
          name:'Series 2',
          value:-9000
        },
        {
          name:'Series 3',
          value:5009
        },
        {
          name:'Series 4',
          value:8900
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Row 4',
      series: [
        {
          name:'Series 1',
          value:8567
        },
        {
          name:'Series 2',
          value:4332
        },
        {
          name:'Series 3',
          value:-3111
        },
        {
          name:'Series 4',
          value:-3222
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Row 5',
      series: [
        {
          name:'Series 1',
          value:8333
        },
        {
          name:'Series 2',
          value:3234
        },
        {
          name:'Series 3',
          value:-7323
        },
        {
          name:'Series 4',
          value:1544
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Row 6',
      series: [
        {
          name:'Series 1',
          value:2112
        },
        {
          name:'Series 2',
          value:3232
        },
        {
          name:'Series 3',
          value:-8231
        },
        {
          name:'Series 4',
          value:1111
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Row 7',
      series: [
        {
          name:'Series 1',
          value:-2112
        },
        {
          name:'Series 2',
          value:3232
        },
        {
          name:'Series 3',
          value:8231
        },
        {
          name:'Series 4',
          value:-9111
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Row 8',
      series: [
        {
          name:'Series 1',
          value:-2112
        },
        {
          name:'Series 2',
          value:100
        },
        {
          name:'Series 3',
          value:-3
        },
        {
          name:'Series 4',
          value:0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I want to find the Max and Min from the datatable with using RxJS, I have done this below to find the Max and Min

```
function findMax(column: DataTableType) {
  let maxN = column[0].series[0].value;
  of(...column)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(
        (item: DataTableType[number], i: number) => from(
          [...item.series]
        )
        .pipe(
          max((a, b) => a.value < b.value? b.value : a.value)
        )
      )
    )
    .subscribe(
      (category: { value: number; }) => {
        maxN = category.value;
      }
    )
  ;
  return maxN;
}

function findMin(column: DataTableType) {
  let minN = column[0].series[0].value;
  of(...column)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(
        (item: DataTableType[number], i: number) => from(
          [...item.series]
        )
        .pipe(
          min((a, b) => a.value > b.value? b.value : a.value)
        )
      )
    )
    .subscribe(
      (category: { value: number; }) => {
        minN = category.value;
      }
    )
  ;
  return minN;
}
```

But whenever I run the functions findMax(datatable) and findMin(datatable) I get max = 0 and min = -2112 of the last element of the object array which is Row 8.

My expected answer should be max = 9120 and min = -9111

Please I need help.

Comment: Why does any of this has to do with rxjs? You don't need rxjs at all, do you? `Math.max`?

Comment: i'm new to RxJS and i'm trying to solve a complex problem with it and in a way to master the behavior of the operators. if RxJS is not possible then i would prefer Math.max

Comment: If this is for fun, good for you man! Hope you enjoy your journey with rjxs. It's pretty awesome and learning by playing is the best way. If you're doing this for production code on the other hand, I'd strongly advise not to do that though

Comment: Why is this tagged vue, react and angularjs? Please pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions given to min and max should behave like the comparator function passed to [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#syntax):

> The return value should be a number whose sign indicates the relative order of the two elements: negative if `a` is less than `b`, positive if `a` is greater than `b`, and zero if they are equal.

Unfortunately, the documentation of RxJS provides this only through examples, i.e. for [`min()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/min) it gives the example:

```
min((a, b) => a.age < b.age ? -1 : 1)
```

Note that `min` and `max` work with the same comparison, you don't have to adjust it depending on whether you want min or max. So in your case, it is `(a,b) => a.value - b.value` for both.

---

A second problem in your functions is that you apply the `min`/`max` to the steam you generate inside the `mergeMap()`, so it will be evaluated for each group, instead of the flattened stream. So you will get a result for every `Row` item, and your variable will be set to each of them, until it is returned with the value from the last iteration.

Instead, apply `min`/`max` after the merge, so that you get the smallest/largest value from the whole stream.

Together with the fixed comparator, this gives you:

```
function findMax(column) {
  let maxN = column[0].series[0].value;
  from(column)
    .pipe(mergeMap(item => item.series))
    .pipe(max((a, b) => a.value - b.value))
    .subscribe(
      (category) => {
        maxN = category.value;
      }
    )
  ;
  return maxN;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can also have the `mergeMap` extract the values directly, then you don't have to use a comparator:

```
function findMax(column) {
  let maxN = column[0].series[0].value;
  from(column)
    .pipe(mergeMap(item => from(item.series).pipe(map(s => s.value))))
    .pipe(max())
    .subscribe(
      (category) => {
        maxN = category;
      }
    )
  ;
  return maxN;
}
```